# Should I check if "std::string.c_str" is NULL?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c++

I am writing code C++ code in Xcode. At an instance I'm making sure that all fields are valid.

```
SomeClass *myclass = new SomeClass();
std::string myString;

if ( (myClass) && (myString.c_str)) {
return true;
} else {
return false;
}
```

Should i be checking for `testString.c_str`? Does it makes sense?

Comment: It makes no sense. `std::string` as a specific API to test various semantic states of the object.

Comment: The first check doesn't make sense either, the `new` operator never returns a null pointer.

Comment: Also `myString.c_str` isn't a valid expression.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Then what do you suggest for the check?

Comment: @StoryTeller do you mean "if (myString.c_str)" is not valid?

Comment: I mean your compiler will complain. Which you would have known had you tested your actual code. Member functions must be **called** with the member access syntax. This isn't a call.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `myString.c_str` is an error. Take some of those redundant parentheses in the `if` statement and put them after the `c_str` so that you have a function call: `if (myClass && myString.c_str())`.

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of the new() operator is to either return the new object, or throw an exception if memory allocation failed. So, you don't need to check if `myClass` is NULL, unless you set the flags to change the behavior or implemented your own new() operator for your class.

Also, the extra brackets around `myClass` are not necessary. A better way to express what you want to check would be

```
if ((myClass != nullptr) &&
```

Then, you are currently testing if the address of the method `c_str()` in the `std::string` class is not NULL. Not want you want to do, I guess.
First, you would need to write `myString.c_str()`. Then, this method never returns a NULL pointer, what it can return is an empty C string. But this is better tested with `std::string::empty()`, so your check would look like this:

```
if (myString.empty()) {
return false;
} else {
return true;
}
```

which can of course be shortened into

```
   return !myString.empty();
```

Finally: If you have this code in a function/method: Who deletes your new SomeClass object?

Comment: SomeClass object is passed as argument to the validation method. So do I need to take care of this as well? I am working on Xcode.

Comment: Well, maybe you should remove the C++ tag then ... I don't know objective-c, in C++ you have to delete the objects yourself that you created with new().